# Use named ranges in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, named-ranges

How can I use a dynamic named range in VBA? For example now I use a named range called "Range1", but the user may choose a different name (I have to work with a lot of named ranges so I need something more general). I am new at this, but should I store the named range in a variable? Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim MyArray
Dim dctCol As dictionary
Dim strKey1 As String

Set dctCol = New dictionary  
MyArray = Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names("Range1").RefersToRange.Address)
For j = 2 To UBound(MyArray , 2) 
    strKey1 = Trim(MyArray (1, j)) & "," & Trim(MyArray (2, j)) & "," & Trim(MyArray (3, j))
    dctCol(strKey1) = j
Next
```

Comment: Should just be `Range("NamedRangeName")`. So for you, `Range("Range1").Value` since your adding it to an array.

Comment: @Simon But what if the user will change the name of the range into "MyRange"? I want that my code to run even if the named range is changed. This is what I mean :(

Comment: You could create another named range that links to the one you want and use that in the code (as it automatically updates when the desired range changes names). Otherwise have the person enter the name of the named range using an `InputBox`

Comment: What is proposed to do if the user **deletes a name** or changes the named area?

Comment: In the end I want to copy cells from a sheet (from another workbook) to that range. So if the Range doesn't exist, the copying will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what is needed. But if you just want to process all the named ranges in a book, regardless of their names, you can just go through the WB name collection:

```vb
Sub ListNamesAddresses()
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        Debug.Print nm.Name, nm.RefersToRange.Address
        'do something with names and it's properties
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Name1         $D$4:$D$21
Name2         $E$4:$E$21
Name3         $F$4:$F$21
Name4         $G$4:$G$21
Name5         $H$4:$H$21
Name6         $I$4:$I$21
```